# the global variable is getting undefined in HTTP call

Tags: typescript, http, global-variables, angular7

I need to get the list of dates from the server by using an API HTTP call. After that, I need to display the background color for that date in a calendar.

Here I'm getting data from HTTP call nicely. That data is assigning to one global variable. That global variable is getting "undefined" after assigning data(Which is getting from server).

**Global variable Declaration:**

unAvailableDays:any=[];

**HTTP call:**

```
beforeMonthViewRender(renderEvent: CalendarMonthViewBeforeRenderEvent): void {
    let startday =this.datepipe.transform(this.startDate,'MM-dd-yyyy');
    let endday = this.datepipe.transform(this.endDate,'MM-dd-yyyy');
    this.sharedService.GetUnAvailableTimeSlotsDatesBetweenTwoDatesByMemberID(this.sharedService.MemberID,startday,endday)
        .subscribe((data:any) => {
            this.unAvailableDays=data,
            console.log( this.unAvailableDays)
        });

    renderEvent.body.forEach(day => {
        const dayOfMonth = day.date.getDate();
        for(var i =0;i<this.unAvailableDays.length;i++) {
            console.log(dayOfMonth);
            if(new Date(this.unAvailableDays[i].date).getDate()==dayOfMonth) {
                day.cssClass = 'bg-pink';
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

`renderEvent` is calling before data assigning to `this.unAvailableDays` which is mentioned inside of HTTP call.

[image: please click here for Exption image]

[image]

Please Help me.

Comment: What about only ```data``` variable, is it filled with data when coming back from server?

Comment: yes @thezeeshantariq, data is getting from server

Comment: @thezeeshantariq, is there any mistakes in my code please let me know.

Comment: Your code is looking OK. Can you check the data-type of your ```data``` variable?

Comment: @thezeeshantariq,Data is mentioned `any`

Comment: Ok, then try to call renderEvent in subscribe function/lambda, or wait for data to be received and then call renderEvent using boolean flag

Comment: @thezeeshantariq I tried render event in subscribe function.It's not working.How can i use wait() for this function untill i get the data

Comment: try to declare variable ```let global = this;``` and then use it like, ```global.unAvailableDays=data;```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the renderEvent code inside the subscribe. You are trying to render something before it is assigned (render code is called most likely before your HTTP call finishes).

As a tip, always align your code properly, you will see it better.

```
beforeMonthViewRender(renderEvent: any): void {
  let startday = this.datepipe.transform(this.startDate, "MM-dd-yyyy");
  let endday = this.datepipe.transform(this.endDate, "MM-dd-yyyy");
  this.sharedService
    .GetUnAvailableTimeSlotsDatesBetweenTwoDatesByMemberID(
      this.sharedService.MemberID,
      startday,
      endday
    )
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.unAvailableDays = data;
      console.log(this.unAvailableDays);

      renderEvent.body.forEach(day => {
        const dayOfMonth = day.date.getDate();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.unAvailableDays.length; i++) {
          console.log(dayOfMonth);
          if (new Date(this.unAvailableDays[i].date).getDate() == dayOfMonth) {
            day.cssClass = "bg-pink";
            break;
          }
        }
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: what is the output of this.unAvailableDays? and does it enter the for loop? Also, show me the contents of renderEvent.body

Comment: yes, it's entering into the loop but  this.unAvailableDays is getting undefined.

Comment: if it enters the forLoop it cannot be undefined. What is logged to the console if you remove all breakpoints?